# webkit browsers are getting elements.width() wrong

Tags: jquery, safari, cross-browser, google-chrome, webkit

I am trying to get the correct calculated width of an container.
All the browsers are getting the calculated width correctly. (even IE) but surprisingly Chrome and webKit browsers are getting a wired number.

I am trying to get the total width of the `<li>` including its border and padding + its margin-right.

Then multiply that by the length of `<li>`'s to get the exact width needed to hold them

I tracked down the problem with the width calculation.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong.

Thanks

**HTML**

```
 <div id="videoTotorialTumbs">
    <a href="#" id="thumbLeftArrow" class="inActive"></a>
   <a href="#" id="thumbRightArrow"></a>
      <div id="horizontalBelt">
        <ul style="width: 1056px;">
            <li><a rel="video1" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/110x90.jpg">     <span>Upload images</span></a></li>
            <li><a rel="video2" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/110x90.jpg"><span>Choose Theme</span></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var videoContext = $("#horizontalBelt"),
 videoBeltUL = videoContext.find("ul"),
 videoBeltLI = videoContext.find("li"),
 videoLength = videoBeltLI.length,
 videoWidth  = parseInt(videoBeltLI.eq(0).outerWidth())+parseInt(videoBeltLI.eq(0).css("marginRight")),
 beltTotalWidth = videoLength*videoWidth,
       // js goes on....
```

beltTotalWidth has a different value in webKit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you calling this from

`$(document).ready(...)` ?

if so try using

`$(window).load(...)`

Comment: This should fix your problem. In chrome it is getting the pre-image width. You are wanting the width after images are loaded which is what the `$(window).load(...)` will give you.

Comment: are your images fixed size ? if so add their width/height dimensions to a css rule or style and try again .. perhaps if the dimensions are fed to the browser it will calculate it correctly..

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to wait for the `window` `load` event, you could run it on each image's `load` event instead. As Gaby said in a comment, if you know the image's dimensions, adding `width` properties to your images would allow you to run it earlier.