# jQuery width() not returning correct value on a div with generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the code below, the alert doesn't return the actual size of #main, it always returns the value of #main's css width with the % dropped.  So in this case I get 95 in the alert.  If I alert parent().width() I get 100.

The data returned from the .get() call is a ul that sometimes is wider than #main, and sometimes not.  The width of the content doesn't seem to have any bearing on what .width() returns.

So my question is, how do I get the true pixel width of #main?

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
}

#main {
    width: 95%;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="conatiner">
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$.get('page.php', function(result) {
    $('#main').html(result);
});
alert($('#main').width();
```

Comment: Very strange, because the doc says that width() will always return value in pixels (http://api.jquery.com/width/) -> "... returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400)"

Comment: Can't reproduce with the provided code: http://jsfiddle.net/w7kqb/1/ Please provide an exemple where this doesn't work.

Comment: You're missing the closing `)` on that alert. I assume that's not that way in your real code?

Comment: Is it possible that the actual width of main is 95 pixels?

Comment: Is `#main` visible in the page?

Comment: Have you tried using the outerWidth() function?

Comment: @Lepidosteus This is all part of a larger project, so there may be something elsewhere causing the problem.  This was my attempt to boil it down to the core parts.  I will see if I can reproduce this outside of the project its in.

Comment: Also, this was not actual code, so the missing ) is not in the actual code.  I have also checked the that the actual width is not 95px.  If I change the css to 1% I get 1.  Or if I change containers width to 20px and leave main with 95% I get 95.  #main is visible on the page.  And I have tried outerWidth(), same results.

Comment: Is this a browser-specific problem, perhaps? What browser(s) are you testing in?

Comment: How come **no-one** noticed that he is calling `.width()` long before the ajax request is even made, let alone completed and executed it's success callback (where the ul is being added to #main)? My god

Comment: The async isn't relevant, except that the element is probably hidden until load. If he calls .width() while it's still hidden, he'll get a percentage fallback as px can't be calc while hidden.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ran into this same issue while trying to implement [jquery.autogrow-textarea](https://github.com/jaz303/jquery-grab-bag/blob/master/javascripts/jquery.autogrow-textarea.js) on textareas used for inline editing. The textareas were contained within `div`'s that were not yet displayed (css `display: none;`).  While debugging the `.autogrow()` javascript code, I discovered that jQuery's `.width()` was returning the percentage value with the '%' character removed as opposed to the calculated width in pixels (e.g. 100 for 100%, 80 for 80%).

Here is the jsfiddle that illustrates this scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/leeives/ujE6s/

To work around this, I changed my code to `.autogrow()` as soon as the textarea was displayed instead.  The calls to `.width()` were then accurate.

I'm not sure if you're working with hidden content or not, but thought I'd write up my answer in case others stumbled upon this (like I did) while searching for an issue with jQuery's `.width()`.

Comment: The only consistent way I got a percentage return from .width() is when the element isn't visible. I think this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same problem.  For whatever reason (environment) I was not able to pull the correct .width() off of a div that had a percentage value for the width in CSS.

The accepted answer to this post:
[webkit browsers are getting elements.width() wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248325/webkit-browsers-are-getting-elements-width-wrong)

where Gaby answered with the suggestion to use: $(window).load(...) worked perfectly.

```
  $(window).load(function () {
     alert($('#main').width();
  });
```

I know it's an old post, but this may be useful info to someone if they don't come across the other post.

Answer (score 3):

This is because AJAX is asynchronous. When you run the `alert`, the request hasn't come back.

Fixed code:

```
$.get('page.php', function(result) {
    $('#main').html(result);
    alert($('#main').width());
});
```

Comment: I'm thinking that the width of the #main isn't affected by it's content.

Answer (score 2):

This works if you fix the last line of your code:

```
alert($('#main').width());
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/UMAbx/

Also, `div id=container` was spelled incorrectly in the HTML.  Fixed in the fiddle.

Comment: The code I wrote above is not the actual code.  It was me breaking the code down to just the important parts.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery **width**() returns the width of an element without its border and padding.

CSS **width** in the other hand could include border and padding (that depends on your browser/css default box model behaviour).
If you need the entire width of the element, you should use jQuery **outerWidth**() instead.

```
$.get('page.php', function(result) {
    $('#main').html(result);
    alert($('#main').outerWidth();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to replicate this behavior.  Perhaps someone overrode `jQuery.fn.width()` with an implementation that returns the value as a percentage?  I'd debug in Firebug or similar and inspect that function to be sure.

Comment: Just to add use something like $.fn.width to get the function which is returning  the value in you browser console.