# JQuery get Element width in PX

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed DIV that runs along the bottom of the page and has several DIV's with it that are set using css width %.

eg: HTML

```
    <div id="footerHide" class="footerDivRightContainers">
      <img src="../../images/footer-divider.png" id="footerDividerHide" class="footerDivider">
      <h3 id="footerHide">Hide</h3>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div#footerHide {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 6%;
    min-width: 50px;
}
```

I'm using Percentage so it re-sizes with the page.

I need to get the width in Pixels and when I run:

```
alert($('div#footerHide').width());
```

I get the result of 6 - which relates to the width: 6%.

Is there a way to get this value in Pixels?

thx

Comment: Gives me 50. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7SKq8/

Comment: chrome... its part of a larger block of code...

Comment: We need more code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which version of jQuery ? ... by the way `$('div#footerHide')` should be written as `$('#footerHide')`

Comment: 1.8.0 - latest I believe

Comment: `.width()` should always return pixels. What happens when you use a percentage other than 6%?

Comment: its shows the number i change it too... very strange... I'm looking at a different way to code this now - many ways to skin a cat... thanks for looking at this :)

Comment: are *you* able to reproduce the issue in the fiddle, or do you only see it in your original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) returns the *computed* width value of an element. Your error cannot be reproduced in jsfiddle with any of the newer versions of jQuery they support or the code you've provided.

This could however be an [issue with retrieving a width value for a hidden element with generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6208951/1081234) - since you're saying there's more code I can only assume this is the case of not providing a detailed enough code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

try using this for webkit and mozilla

```
alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("footerHide")).width);
```

and this for IE

```
alert(document.getElementById("footerHide").currentStyle.width);
```