# Backbone view and jquery width returns percentage

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to calculate if a table is wider then it's container div using backbone, handlebars, underscore and jQuery. The problem is that the .width() function from jQuery returns a percentage and not the pixels.

I've read a few posts about this e.g. [jQuery width() not returning correct value on a div with generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208951/jquery-width-not-returning-correct-value-on-a-div-with-generated-content) where it is stated that elements which are not attached to the html document yet will get the css width. This makes sense, the table is retrieved from a database and it has a css-width in percentage, which I cannot control.

```
...
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
                template: Handlebars.compile(myTemplate),
                tagName: 'div',
                id: 'my-doc-container',
                headerTag: 'h2',
                options: null,
                initialize: function(options) {
                    this.options = options;
                },
                setModel: function(parentModelOptions) {
                    this.model = new MyDocModel(parentModelOptions);
                    ...
                    this.render();
                },
                render: function() {
                    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                    this._adaptContent();

                    return this;
                },
                _adaptContent: function() {
                    var tables = $(this.$el).find('table');
                    ...
                    _.each(tables, function(table) {
                        $(table).wrap('<div class="tablewrapper"/>');

                        alert($table).width());
                    }, this);
                }
                ...
              }
           })
```

So my question is if any one has any suggestions on how I could be able to calculate the width of the table from within these frameworks?

Comment: PS: `$(this.$el).find('table')` is an overly complicated way of saying `this.$('table')`: http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar And you have an extra `)` in `alert($table).width())`.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, u are not able to get elements width (same on diplay: none property, and more cases...),
but u can pass element which is in dom already.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: Handlebars.compile(myTemplate),
  el: "selector of element what is available in dom already like div#myTable",

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(.....));
    this.$el.width() // => return right result

    return this;
  }  
});
```

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing when I do the `var tables = $(this.$el).find('table');`? This should get the tables from the rendered html document into the variable, right?

Comment: Nope, $(this.$el) is same like this.$el and you take new element with html inside, which is not rendered to dom... after `this.$el.appendTo ....` will take the effect. So you need to first render el and after asking for width...

Comment: Well I even went as far as creating a new method which is called directly after render() is called, so that it is absolutely created after render has finished... it still just returns percentages..

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, thank you for the help, but my problem seems to be related to this view being a sub-classed view and the rendering procedures of backbone in this circumstance. This makes it a bit more difficult to post on jsfiddle since my particular problem is nestled in more than one part/file of backbone... I will see if I can clarify the issue later if the time is available.